# Compute p-value in a contingency table other than 2x2 table

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I guess I have a newby question here. I have used the tableone R package to create the contingency table shown below. I am struggling to understand which test was used by the package to compute the p-values. I guess ordinary chisq.test was performed but I am not sure. For a fischer.test the table should be in a 2x2 format, right? But I have cells with very small counts and fisher test is recommended in that case.

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
catVars = "Gender"

contVars = c(
    "Profession",
    "Your expert level"
)

tableOne <-
    CreateTableOne(
        data = survey_data,
        vars = contVars,
        testExact = fisher.test,     
        addOverall = FALSE,
        strata = catVars
    )


results_tbl <- print(tableOne, nonnormal = biomarkers, exact = "stage", quote = FALSE, noSpaces = FALSE, printToggle = FALSE)
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You should consider copying and pasting your code in order to increase the clarity of your post.

Comment: Here we go ... sorry for that :)

Comment: If you do summary(results_tbl), it'll tell you which p value from which test it has printed: either pApprox or pExact.

Answer (score 0):

Fisher's exact test can be implemented for any contingency table, not just 2 x 2 tables. However, when the table is large and/or the number of observations are large, it can be computationally infeasible because the exact test involves generating every  possible table. Instead, of generating every possible table, a random sample of possible tables can be generated. That's the difference between pExact and pApprox that Elizabethral notes above.